# How to display Content from Already created list using ACF to another page

Tags: wordpress

I want to reuse my list on another page. When the user clicks on it, it will have content on it

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row featured-boxes">
    <?php 
      $loop = new WP_Query( array(
        'post_type' => 'course_library', 
        'orderby' => 'post_id', 
        'order' => 'ASC'
      )); 

    while ($loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post(); ?>
      <div class="col-md-3">
        <div style="height: 2572px;" class="featured-box">
          <h4><?php echo the_field('main_heading'); ?></h4>
          <?php $your_topics = get_field('your_topic_title_1'); ?>
          <ul class="menu" id="java_technologies">
            <?php foreach($your_topics as $your_topic) { ?>
              <li><a target="_top" href="/"><?php echo $your_topic['list_items']; ?></a></li>
            <?php } ?>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
    <?php endwhile; ?>
  </div>
</div>
```

I am using ACF pro with Repeater addon and a custom Post type UI Plugin. I created a Custom post type named course library and there I added a few fields and sub fields using repeater. Now I want these sub-fields to be linked with the posts to display content on each page.

For example, a css list has the field CSS positioning. Now I have too add content on CSS positioning which will be displayed on another page. How do I do this?

Comment: Did you check out the docs? `get_field()` accepts an optional `post_id` parameter, which allows you to get a field from any post, not just the one you're currently looping through. http://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/get_field/

Comment: Right. but How do I get it work? for example if I will have to post multiple content daily. how post_id will work for this? and where do I add this?